# Need help to make a event handler to work properly in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to make this logic to be executed every time when input field value is changed:

```
  let warningMessage = ''

  if (stateData) {
    let list = []
    if (props.values.injured_worker_type === 'Seasonal') {
      list = stateData.calculation_warnings['Seasonal']
    } else {
      list = stateData.calculation_warnings[`FullTime-${props.values.working_days}`]
    }

    const keys = _.keys(list)
    const index = _.findIndex(keys, key => {
      const fromValue = Number(key.slice(1, key.indexOf('-')))
      const toValue = Number(key.slice(key.indexOf('-') + 1, key.length))
      return props.values.total_days_paid >= fromValue && props.values.total_days_paid < toValue
    })

    if (index >= 0) {
      warningMessage = list[keys[index]]
    }
  }

  const message = warningMessage ? (
    <p style={{ color: 'red', fontSize: '0.85rem' }}> {warningMessage} </p>
  ) : null
```

**And pass downthis messeage to be outputed as result of this logic:**

```
  const message = warningMessage ? (
   <p style={{ color: 'red', fontSize: '0.85rem' }}> {warningMessage} </p>
  ) : null
```

---

**Here is JSX(html) part when I have that input field:**

```
 return (
<Fragment>
  <Form.Group grouped style={{ marginTop: '2rem' }}>
    <label style={{ fontSize: '0.85rem' }}>8. Total days in preceeding 52 weeks:</label>
    <Form.Input
      name="total_days_paid"
      onChange={this.handleChange}
      width="6"
      placeholder="200"
      required
    />
  </Form.Group>

 {/* THIS messeage is result of that logic which I need to 
     be executed every time on changed input */}
      {message}
    </Fragment>
```

)
}

Here is **not working** version of code in stackblitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-tpk1ik

How I can make this to works?

Comment: I see this error at your online demo: "Import error, can't find file: semantic-ui-react"

Comment: Yup, that is not working version. just representation of code, to be easier for reading.

Comment: You should create a minimal working example of your code, it'd make it easier for us to help you. I already installed the two missing dependencies but your code doesn't help much because it outputs nothing.

Comment: Ok @thinkxl  I am gonna make working version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code is not up to the mark. You are doing many mistakes in your code.

I have corrected all your code and here is the working solution of handler function https://react-t3luq3.stackblitz.io.

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDom from "react-dom";
import Hello from './Hello';

ReactDom.render(<Hello />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

**Hello.js**

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react'
import { Form } from 'semantic-ui-react'
import _ from 'lodash'

export default class Hello extends Component{

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
  }
  handleChange = e => {
    console.log(e.target.value)
  }

  render(){
  const { stateData } = this.props;

  let warningMessage = ''

  if (stateData) {
    let list = []
    if (props.values.injured_worker_type === 'Seasonal') {
      list = stateData.calculation_warnings['Seasonal']
    } else {
      list = stateData.calculation_warnings[`FullTime-${props.values.working_days}`]
    }

    const keys = _.keys(list)
    const index = _.findIndex(keys, key => {
      const fromValue = Number(key.slice(1, key.indexOf('-')))
      const toValue = Number(key.slice(key.indexOf('-') + 1, key.length))
      return props.values.total_days_paid >= fromValue && props.values.total_days_paid < toValue
    })

    if (index >= 0) {
      warningMessage = list[keys[index]]
    }
  }

  const message = warningMessage ? (
    <p style={{ color: 'red', fontSize: '0.85rem' }}> {warningMessage} </p>
  ) : null
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <Form.Group grouped style={{ marginTop: '2rem' }}>
        <label style={{ fontSize: '0.85rem' }}>8. Total days in preceeding 52 weeks:</label>
        <Form.Input
          name="total_days_paid"
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          width="6"
          placeholder="200"
          required
        />
      </Form.Group>
        {message}
    </Fragment>
  )
}
}
```

**index.html**

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hey thnk twice, thanks on helping. I cannot see code on link which you provide. Can you send me the code preview?

Comment: @JamesDelaney really I am able to see the code on this link https://react-t3luq3.stackblitz.io

Comment: NP I have added it in my answer. Check my updated answer

Comment: @JamesDelaney Hey here is editable code https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-t3luq3?file=Hello.js

Answer (score 1):

The code in your example doesn't help much because it has errors and even when I install the missing dependencies it outputs nothing, but just from reading it I can see an issue.

The logic you want to execute when the `input` value changes needs to go inside the `handleChange` method you are trying to call here `onChange={this.handleChange}`.

For reference, these type of `input` fields are called [Controled Components](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components) and you can read more about them in the [React Documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components).